# new array with just values in php

Tags: php, laravel, export-to-csv

So i'm writing a simple export csv function in php however, i'm having a bit of a problem when it comes to headers and array for values.

I have a preset array of which columns the user can export, which is `$exportHeaders`. So what i'm trying to do, instead of typing each value for `$row['value for column']` i want to create a way to make a new array to insert instead of `$row` section. However, when i make a new array, which is `$newExportHeader[]` in my case, i end up with an array that looks like this (with key and value ):

```
$newExportHeader = array(
0 => $row['first_name'],
1 => $row['last_name'],
2 => $row['email'],
);
```

But i need an array that does not have a key associated with it.  **So my question is: is there any way to make an array on the fly without keys in it, only values**

```
protected $exportHeaders = array(
    "first_name", "last_name", "email", "street", "city", "province", "postal_code", "phone_1",
    "phone_2", "created_at", "updated_at"

);
```

This currently works:

```
foreach ($this->user->clients()->get() as $row) {
            fputcsv($handle, array(row['first_name'], row['last_name'], row['email']));
        }
```

One of the options that I was playing around with - doesn't work:

```
foreach ($this->user->clients()->get() as $row) {
        foreach ($this->exportHeaders as $header) {
                $newExportHeader[] = $row[$header]; <-Problem Area
            }
            fputcsv($handle, array_values($newExportHeader));
        }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: An array without keys, Doh!! Whats that? I guess you could call it a comma delimited string

Comment: PHP does not allow arrays without keys. If you make an array "without keys", like this `$foo = array("one", "two", "three");`, PHP will automatically index it so that `$foo[0] === "one"`. Thus, an array "without keys" is the same as an indexed array starting at 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your working code, and guessing what you're going for based on your non-working code,

Try this:

```
foreach ($this->user->clients()->get() as $row) {
    $transformedRow = array(); // Create a new array for the row, based on new headers.
    foreach($this->exportHeaders as $header) {
        $transformedRow[] = row[$header]; // Add to the new array for the row in the correct order.
    }
    fputcsv($handle, $transformedRow); // Add row to the csv
}
```

In your original code, you seem to have a problem in that you don't re-initialize `$newExportHeader` each iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: You're a lifesaver man! Thank you. Worked like a charm. I've been banging my head against the desk for 2 days on this. This will save repeating code in other parts of the program.